# Enable FTP on a Linux machine

Tags: linux, ftp

How do I find out or know whether or not an FTP client is enabled or disabled on my Linux machine?

If it is disabled, how do I enable it?

I have a Linux 2.6.9-67.ELsmp

Comment: As implied in my answer below.  If you install Open SSHD on your system, as everyone should do,  you can avoid FTP, and get a much more secure file transfer (SFTP) that works just as easily as FTP would.  And, obviously, if you want a SFTP client, use psftp .

Answer (score 2):

type `ftp` in the shell and look for what it says.

Comment: Simple and most likely effective. :)

Answer (score 2):

For future reference, use:

https://serverfault.com/

https://superuser.com/

Downvoted, but to be constructive:

I assume you mean FTP server and not client. You could try `ftp localhost` to see if you're running one. How to "enable" it depends on your distribution. Shot in the dark might be `sudo apt-get install proftpd` or similar.

Comment: yaa ftp server means i would like to simple do file transfer using ftp

Comment: Its actually more difficult (slightly) to setup a regular FTP server than it is to use SFTP.  You might as well use SFTP.

Answer (score 0):

To enable FTP , just install the package  "sshd" .   Then you can connect to your server with a SFTP client like Putty  or PSFTP.

Comment: ssh(d) does not provide a FTP server.  (it might provide an sFTP server but depite the similar names they are quite different. FTP is ancient, plain text and not used anymore. sFTP is much more modern and uses encryption).

Comment: @Hennes - you are incorrect about that.  starting with version 5, there is an available SFTP subsystem for sshd.  Notice that I did not suggest that he use FTPS.